# Ruby On Rails and Challonge API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tournament

I'm pretty new, but getting the concepts of Ruby on Rails. I'm trying to get a tournament up and running. I added the gem as a dependency in the Gem file; however, I'm unsure where to add my username and API key. This is the API  - https://bitbucket.org/corneldm/challonge-api/wiki/Home - And what about displaying the the filtered list in view "Challonge::Tournament.find(:all)." I'm not sure how to connect the preconfigured ActiveResource classes. Has anyone experienced Challonge API for Ruby? Or Another bracket system I could use?

Answer (score 0):

a file in config/initializers would be the conventional place to put that configuration info, probably in challone.rb so its clear what is getting initialized

Answer (score 0):

If you have environment-specific user names and API keys, then you can consider /environments/.rb

Comment: How to use the example they use:
Basic Usage
Get all your tournaments:

Challonge::Tournament.find(:all)
Get a filtered set of tournaments:

Challonge::Tournament.find(:all, :params => {:state => 'in_progress'})